# Attempt to present UINavigationController on non-existent UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have this error right now:

> `Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x10d80b800> on
>   <UINavigationController: 0x109891a00> whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!`

I've seen this before and usually it has to do with `viewDidLoad` versus another place where trying to present, but that isn't the case here.

My flow:

LoginViewController (NOT A UINavigationController):

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToMainVC", sender: nil)

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        if identifier == "GoToMainVC" {
            segue.destination.transitioningDelegate = self
            segue.destination.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        }
    }
}
```

ProfileViewController (which is a ViewController in a UINavigationController):

`self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)`

Before, I've also had `self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true)` for ProfileViewController, but it shouldn't matter.

When my application goes through the segue the first time, everything is fine and the UINavigationController is `<UINavigationController: 0x10d81a000>`.

After I go through the dismiss and try to segue again, I get the warning above, where `<UINavigationController: 0x10d81a000>` is trying to be presented on `<UINavigationController: 0x109891a00>`. I have no idea where the second UINavigationController comes from, as LoginViewController is not a UINavigationController.

Totally stumped here.

**Update: I fixed my bug by explicitly using `self.presentViewController` instead of the segue, but I'm leaving this here... because it is extremely odd to me and I'd like to know why this would happen.**

Comment: I literally have no idea what is happening. `segue.source` is never a UINavigationController.

Comment: Error message is quite self explanatory, you're trying to present `UINavigationController` on view controller whose view is not in the window hierarchy.

Comment: Not really providing enough info for us to help with any specifics.

Comment: Did you perhaps wire your segue from a button instead of from the viewController icon at the top of the VC?  You want to do the latter if you are triggering the segue with `performSegue`.